# jQuery Datatables rendering call method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

I need to execute the `MethodStatus` to return the string value in the calumn

currently says Method is unrecognized variable

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MethodStatus

```
MethodStatus(data){
     if(data===0)
     return "Disable"
     else
     return "Active"
   },

getMethod() {
     this.loading = true
     this.datatable1 = $("#table").DataTable({
       ajax: {
         url:
         `users`, dataSrc: "user"
       },
       columns: [
         {  data: "status",
             render: function(data){ return MethodStatus(data) }
         },
```

Comment: When you say "DataTable", do you mean you are using this library? https://datatables.net/

Comment: Yes, Alex Kong...

Comment: since JS is extremely flexible, so I am not sure if my way is the only way, but usually I define a function like this `function myFunction() {}`, but your `MethodStatus()` does **not** have a `function` keyword?

Comment: is inside a method: { of vue

Comment: try using arrow function `render: (data) => MethodStatus(data)`

Comment: Could you please add the sorrounding code to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Generally, Vue and jQuery don't necessarily work together nicely since jQuery modifies the DOM which Vue doesn't like. Maybe it's easier to find a similar table component written in Vue.